# preg_replace() not working on node title in hook_preprocess_page()

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

Here's code from my module:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // load the node object
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $fied = $node->field_building_sell['und'][0]['value'];

  // regexp
  $pattern = '/(\w+\s\w+,\s\w+\s.{3}\s\/\/\s\w+)(.*)/i';
  $replacement = '$1';
  $subject = $node->title;
  $replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);

  $variables['title'] = $replaced; 

  dpm($replaced);
}
```

My node title looks like this:

**building Sell, Alatau r-n // City - mon, 03/03/2014 - 22:29**

But i still get the full node title unchanged. Is `preg_replace()` not working in preprocess_page hook?

**UPDATE**

I have noticed, if i replace:

```
$subject = $node->title;
```

to

```
$subject = 'building Sell, Alatau r-n // City - mon, 03/03/2014 - 22:29';
```

It works! But it's not working with `$node->title`, though, node title output is exactly the same as the string i posted above.

Comment: Did you check the pattern works outside Drupal, for the same strings?

Comment: Yes, it works. But in Drupal it doesn't. Mysterious...

Comment: I'm assuming the value you posted is the output of `dpm($replaced)`. Can you also post the value of `$subject`?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Value of the $subject is exactly the same.

Comment: What's the exact output of `$node->title`? My guess is that it doesn't just contain the text you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Just did dpm($node->title) and noticed extra white-space here:

```
building  Sell, Alatau r-n // City - mon, 03/03/2014 - 22:29
```

Though, when i was just printing it `$node->title` it didn't showed any extra white-spaces.